# Using an array as input into a function?

Tags: python, arrays, function

```
X = 
[[14.23  3.06  5.64  2.43]
 [13.2   2.76  4.38  2.14]
 [13.16  3.24  5.68  2.67]
 [14.37  3.49  7.8   2.5 ]
 [13.24  2.69  4.32  2.87]
 [14.2   3.39  6.75  2.45]
 [14.39  2.52  5.25  2.45]
 [14.06  2.51  5.05  2.61]
 [14.83  2.98  5.2   2.17]
 [13.86  3.15  7.22  2.27]
 [14.1   3.32  5.75  2.3 ]
 [14.12  2.43  5.    2.32]
 [13.75  2.76  5.6   2.41]
 [14.75  3.69  5.4   2.39]
 [14.38  3.64  7.5   2.38]
 [13.63  2.91  7.3   2.7 ]
 [14.3   3.14  6.2   2.72]
 [13.83  3.4   6.6   2.62]
 [14.19  3.93  8.7   2.48]
 [13.64  3.03  5.1   2.56]]
```

Here is my dataset. Now I want to calculate the Euclidean distance for 2 of vectors (rows).

```
Row1 = X[1]
Row2 = X[2]
```

My function:

```
def Edistance (v1, v2):
      distance = 0.0 
      for i in range(len(v1)-1):
        distance += (v1(i)) - (v2(i))**2
      return sqrt(distance)        


Edistance(Row1,Row2)
```

I then get Typerror: NumPy array is not callable. Can I not use an array in my functions input?

Comment: You cannot index into an array like that, you need `v1[i]`. Same for `v2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any object as a function argument and so you can pass arrays, but as `@xdurch0` mentioned earlier, your syntax is wrong.

```py
def Edistance (v1: dict, v2: dict): # You 
      distance = 0.0 
      for i in range(len(v1)-1):
        distance += (v1(i)) - (v2(i))**2
      return sqrt(distance)
```

What you try to do here is to call `v1` and `v2` as if they were a functions, since `()` used to execute the commands. But what you want to do, as far as i understand, is to use `[]` to reference at the element inside the array.

So, basically, you want to do `v1[i]` and `v2[i]` (instead of `v1(i)` and `v2(i)` respectively).

Comment: Wow. How could I have missed something so obvious.Thanks.